TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): manager_inheritance_from_future in Django4.2
I got above error while running the makemiragtions command. So I delete/renamed the existing migration folder and rerun the makemirations command it's is migrated but when I run the migrate I got same error i.e., TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): manager_inheritance_from_future.
Here is my model class.
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class CountryList(models.Model):

    CHOICES =[(1, 'Active'), (0, 'Inactive')]

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    iso3_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, verbose_name="ISO Code 3", help_text="ISO code with 3 leaters")
    iso2_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, verbose_name="ISO Code 2", help_text="ISO code with 2 leaters")    
    is_active = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Country_list'
        verbose_name = 'Country'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Countries'
        ordering = ['name','is_active']


Note: I migrated from Django2.2 to Django4.2 version.
So please let me know any one have idea bout it.
Here is my entire error Trackback:
Operations to perform: Apply all migrations: admin, auth, careers, cms, contenttypes, emailsignup, fluent_contents, news, optionsquote, press, redirects, resource, retailfinder, sessions, sites Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/developemt/Documents/Repos/Djnago_axv/manage.py", line 10, in <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) File "/Users/developemt/Documents/Repos/Djnago_axv/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute() File "/Users/developemt/Documents/Repos/Djnago_axv/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv) File "/Users/developemt/Documents/Repos/Djnago_axv/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv self.execute(*args, **cmd_options) File "/Users/developemt/Documents/Repos/Djnago_axv/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute output = self.handle(*args, **options) File "/Users/developemt/Documents/Repos/Djnago_axv/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 106, in wrapper res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs) File "/Users/developemt/Documents/Repos/Djnago_axv/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 302, in handle pre_migrate_apps = pre_migrate_state.apps File "/Users/developemt/Documents/Repos/Djnago_axv/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__ res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance) File "/Users/developemt/Documents/Repos/Djnago_axv/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 566, in apps return StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models) File "/Users/developemt/Documents/Repos/Djnago_axv/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 627, in __init__ self.render_multiple([*models.values(), *self.real_models]) File "/Users/developemt/Documents/Repos/Djnago_axv/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 665, in render_multiple model.render(self) File "/Users/developemt/Documents/Repos/Djnago_axv/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 956, in render return type(self.name, bases, body) File "/Users/developemt/Documents/Repos/Djnago_axv/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 143, in __new__ new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label)) File "/Users/developemt/Documents/Repos/Djnago_axv/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 371, in add_to_class value.contribute_to_class(cls, name) File "/Users/developemt/Documents/Repos/Djnago_axv/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 232, in contribute_to_class raise TypeError( TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): manager_inheritance_from_future 
I have tried by adding up
manager_interface_from_future = True or False

as options in Meta class and also I comment out the entire Meta class of this class but no use.
Note: I have nother model class with Meta calss with same options.

Your model's Meta class doesn't have that attribute though? Please share a [mre], show either a model that has that attribute or a migration file.

manager_inheritance_from_future was supported in Django 1.11 and they kept this Meta option in Django 2.2 for backwards compatibility with Django 1.11 but this option is no longer supported in Django 4.2.
So I think somewhere in your old migrations it sets manager_inheritance_from_future in your model options.

@Abdul Aziz Barkat, Thanks, I previously checked only the models.py files of all the apps,  but when I checked the files in the migrations folder I observed it.
Just One clarification, is it good to remove it from 0001_initial.py or should I run the makemirations command for all the apps.?

@Ramakrishna deleting and removing migrations is mostly not a good idea. You should go ahead and edit the migration, it is Python code and meant to be reviewed and potentially edited anyway.

@Ramakrishna deleting the migrations is not recommended. just modify them and do migrate.

@forsythe - Thanks for your suggestion. Just I modified the migrations files.
